# What does a single exclamation mark do in YAML?

Tags: .net, parsing, tags, yaml, yamldotnet

I'm working with the [YamlDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yamldotnet/) library and I'm getting this error when loading a YAML file:

> While parsing a tag, did not find expected tag URI.

The YAML file is supposed to be well-formed because it comes [right from RoR](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-GB.yml). The error seems to be triggered by this code:

```
formats:
  default: ! '%d-%m-%Y'
  long: ! '%d %B, %Y'
  short: ! '%d %b'
```

I'm not an expert, but I see from the YAML spec that you can use an exclamation mark to indicate a custom object/type, and two exclamation marks to indicate an explicit built-in type.

```
obj1: !custom # whatever
obj2: !!str "My string"
```

However I haven't been able to find any reference to an exclamation mark used as above. What does that mean, and why the YAML library I use doesn't seem able to parse it? Note that if I remove those exclamation marks, the file is parsed fine.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

That `!` is the **non-specific tag**.

The [YAML specification 1.2](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2784064) (as well as the previous [1.1](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id900262)) says that :

> By explicitly specifying a “!” non-specific tag property, the node
> would then be resolved to a “vanilla” sequence, mapping, or string,
> according to its kind.

Take a look [here](http://yaml.org/refcard.html) to the tag "grammar":

> ```
> none    : Unspecified tag (automatically resolved by application).
> '!'     : Non-specific tag (by default, "!!map"/"!!seq"/"!!str").
> '!foo'  : Primary (by convention, means a local "!foo" tag).
> '!!foo' : Secondary (by convention, means "tag:yaml.org,2002:foo").
> '!h!foo': Requires "%TAG !h! <prefix>" (and then means "<prefix>foo").
> '!<foo>': Verbatim tag (always means "foo").
> ```

Why is YamlDotNet throwing a error? I can't be 100% sure, but I think you found a bug.

YamlDotNet is a port of [LibYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML), so it's easy to compare sources.

Line 2635 of scanner.c (LibYAML):

```
/* Check if the tag is non-empty. */
if (!length) {
```

Line 2146 of Scanner.cs (YamlDotNet ):

```
// Check if the tag is non-empty.
if (tag.Length == 0)
```

I know, both looks very similar, but at this point `length` is 1 and `tag.Length` is 0. Original C code takes care of the initial "!" (whole length) but C# doesn't do it (just the tag "name" length).

File an issue to the project.

Comment: Commenting the check seems to fix the problem, but I have no idea about its effect on other constructs. I've filed a bug on the project anyway.

Comment: would it be equivalent to wrap the entire string in quotation marks instead of using the single exclamation mark in front?

Comment: links to specifications should be fixed (1.1 - link to 1.2, 1.2 - links to 1.1)

Comment: The explanation is a little opaque. Do you have an example of using`!` (or any of the variants you mentioned)?

Comment: I'm agreed with Burhan, that's impossible to decipher without having more experience with YAML. This answer elaborates a little more on tags themselves: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17192241/828584