# What do the exclamation marks in Rails i18N translation yml file mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm using Rails i18n to localize my website.

In the translation yml file, I see

```
time:
    am: am
    formats:
      default: ! '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
      long: ! '%d %B, %Y %H:%M'
      short: ! '%d %b %H:%M'
    pm: pm
```

(taken from https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-GB.yml)

What does the exclamation mark mean?  How is it different if you take away the exclamation mark?

Thanks

Comment: Did you _try_ removing them to see if you could notice any difference? What happened to the adventuring spirit?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664113/what-does-a-single-exclamation-mark-do-in-yaml

Comment: I've read the link posted by @Stefan but I'm still don't understand how this applies to Rails.

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664113/what-does-a-single-exclamation-mark-do-in-yaml

Comment: @Stefan - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn I've marked it as a duplicate

Answer (score 9):

% is a special character in YAML.
Single exclamation mark avoids it to be parsed as a special character and passes it as a String.

Comment: would it be equivalent to wrap the entire string in quotation marks instead of using the single exclamation mark in front?

Answer (score 2):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> See [What does a single exclamation mark do in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664113/what-does-a-single-exclamation-mark-do-in-yaml)

~ link per [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan), linked question answered by [Juan Mellado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209430/juan-mellado)