# what is "!" meaning on rails i18n locale file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'v learned i18n locales file from svenfuchs/rails-i18n

one usage I don't get it:
...
date:
  formats:
    default: ! '%m-%d-%Y'
...

What is "!" here meaning ?

if this is a stupid question, forgive me.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

It means it's a "non-specific tag", which just means it should be treated as a string or array, etc by whatever is handling the YAML.

See more here:
http://yaml.org/refcard.html

And there's also a good explanation in this post:
[What does a single exclamation mark do in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664113/what-does-a-single-exclamation-mark-do-in-yaml)

Comment: thanks for the answer and links provided. I searched the "!" rather than "exclamation" before I ask, so missed those with answer to my question.

Comment: No problem. If my answer (or any answer) was helpful, feel free to vote for it and/or mark it as the solution.