# Ansible Playbook Syntax Issue

Tags: ansible, syntax-error, amazon-vpc

I am having an issue with ansible playbook that I am using to setup my AWS VPC.

Here is the snippet of YML file that is causing the issue

```
Outputs:
  TemplateID:
    Description: cloudonaut.io template id
    Value: vpc/vpc-2azs
  StackName:
    Description: Stack name
    Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}'
```

The last line is where the syntax error is being raised. The error is

```
 [WARNING]: Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-config/chalktalk-config/cloudformation/vpc2az.yaml': line 233, column 13, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    Description: Stack name
    Value:  !Sub '${AWS::StackName}'
            ^ here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into YAML tag syntax. See [What does a single exclamation mark do in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664113/what-does-a-single-exclamation-mark-do-in-yaml) for more info.

The quick answer is to wrap the `Value` variable with double quotes.

```
Value:  "!Sub '${AWS::StackName}'"
```

Comment: Please be kind to add explanation about `!` in YAML