# What is !! (double exclamation marks) in YAML?

Tags: yaml

I have this snippet in a longer YAML:

```
config:
  operations: !!map
```

IntelliJ marks the `!!` as error (*expected key-val pair or array item*), probably a false positive.
I wanted to understand more about it so I opened [YAML specifications](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/) but I am still not sure about its use.

Is it used to specify a type or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a single exclamation mark do in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664113/what-does-a-single-exclamation-mark-do-in-yaml)

Comment: It mentions is but it is not specifically related to it...
I did not find the answer you suggest because the title specifically mentions "single" :)

Comment: yeah. they may have different meanings. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the document you linked, it says that `!!` is a Secondary Handle or a Core type (Generic Mapping)

> Secondary Handle
>
> The secondary tag handle is written as “!!”. This allows using a compact notation for a single “secondary” name space. By default, the prefix associated with this handle is “tag:yaml.org,2002:”.

Further example usages on https://yaml.org/refcard.html is as follows

> ...
> '!foo'  : Primary (by convention, means a local "!foo" tag).
> '!!foo' : Secondary (by convention, means "tag:yaml.org,2002:foo").
> ...
> Core types: # Default automatic tags.
> '!!map' : { Hash table, dictionary, mapping }
> '!!seq' : { List, array, tuple, vector, sequence }
> '!!str' : Unicode string
>
> More types:
> '!!set' : {cherries, plums, apples }
> '!!omap': [ one: 1, two: 2 ]

In your example, it defines that `operations` is a map that can have other values.
Can see more info here [Generic Mapping](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#10111-generic-mapping)

```
Block style: !!map
  Clark : Evans
  Ingy  : döt Net
  Oren  : Ben-Kiki

Flow style: !!map { Clark: Evans, Ingy: döt Net, Oren: Ben-Kiki }
```

Comment: why need? i don't see anything wrong if you remove `!!map` in the block style.

Comment: @LeiYang It's generally not needed. YAML specifies that mappings get assigned this tag implicitly *but* you can theoretically define a YAML schema that would assign a different tag implicitly, and could then use `!!map` to prevent that. Nobody does this because YAML is used a bit differently from how it was originally envisioned.